# Simple Jquery toggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a really simple Jquery function that mimicks the code in many online tutorials, an i have looked at a couple of similar stackoverflow questions, but i can't understand why nothing happens when i click the link to show/hide the div called 'advanced-search'. (I have also removed turbolinks but nothing happens too. I do have other Jquery codes present throughout the app and all work fine).

**articles/index.html.erb**

```
    <div class="advanced-search">
       Some code
    </div>

    <a class="show-advanced-search">Advanced Search</a>
```

**articles.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.show-advanced-search').click(function(){
    $('.advanced-search').toggle();  
  });
});
```

Narrowing selector down to `'a.show-advanced-search'` does not work either.

**EDIT:**

I have another Jquery file called "articles.coffee" below with an ajax callback, thought that it could be the one affecting the other jQuery code. However, i have tried deleting "articles.coffee" and the same issue remains.

Copying and pasting the code in articles.js into the browser console works. No errors in browser console.

**articles.coffee**

```
jQuery(document).on 'change', 'select.sortBy', () ->
  $.ajax(
    url: $(this).data('url') + '?type=' + this.value
    type: 'GET'
    contentType: 'script'
    processData: false
  )
  return
```

**my original application.js file**

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.transit.js
//= require turbolinks
//= require articles.js
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: any error in browser console? did you added jQuery library before script code? Did you included your js file in current html file?

Comment: I am not able to replicate it

Comment: @AlivetoDie the jQuery code works only if i paste it into the console and fire it. Yup, i added jQuery library

Comment: since `articles.js` is a separate file so you have to add this file also in your current html too. just under the jQuery library

Answer (score 1):

If you have included `jquery.js` and `articles.js` in order. Then next issue could be `turbolinks` If you are using it.

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  // Do your code
})
```

> NOTE : on Rails >= 4 its there. Please check that.

Answer (score 0):

If it's loaded at the same time the page loads, it shouldn't present any error. But if this is part of the code of a pop-up that appears after clicking on a button you should try this:

```
<pre>$(document).ready(function(){
  // we assum the pop-up container loads at the same time the page is loaded
  $('div.pop_up_container').on("click",".show-advanced-search",function(){
    $(this).next('.advanced-search').toggle();
  });
});</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi try this as **articles.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.show-advanced-search').click(function(){
    $('.advanced-search').toggle();  
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/16526/)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by combining the articles.coffee and articles.js files.

**articles.coffee**

```
jQuery(document).on 'click', 'a.show-advanced-search', () ->
    $('.advanced-search').toggle()
```

Seems as though having 2 separate files and even specifying both in application.js do not work.